# Androdi Studio: dev environments on different machines use different sdk path

Tags: windows, ubuntu, android-studio, sdk

Due to my current situation, I am using dropbox to house all of my Android Studio projects. I'm a solo developer, therefor multiple people writing one file isn't an issue. I can't afford a private GitHub repo atm, and don't want to 'release' the code I work on at the moment.

However, I use my desktop (windows 7) and my laptop (ubuntu 16.04) for dev. For these reasons, I used dropbox.

When I last open a project in one dev environment, and then open it again in the other, the sdk path changes (obviously). On windows it is /users/ME/etc, and on ubuntu it's something different. When I open the project, Android Studio automatically detects the correct sdk path, and says it will modify the local resource.

If I was using GitHub I could just add ./idea to my ignore file, and pushing and pulling would be a breeze.

Is there a way I can solve this minor annoyance using my current setup?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119613/is-there-a-way-to-tell-dropbox-not-to-upload-a-certain-file-eclipse-related#answer-12120384

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Use Bitbucket instead Github. Bitbucket allows you to have private Git repositories for free.

Solution 2: Put your Android SDK on a NAS (Network Attached Disk) and provide in "Settings" that unique network SDK path to both Android Studio's enviroments (Ubuntu and Windows).

Solution 3: Put your Android SDK on a USB stick or USB disk and plug and provide in "Settings" that unique SDK path to both Android Studio's enviroments (Ubuntu and Windows).